# Adding specific labels to legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

Goal: add numeric labels(number of bar on the plot) to legend, e.g 
1.Company X 
2.Company Y 
3.Company Z

```
library(ggplot2)
require(scales)

companies = c('Company X','Company Y','Company Z')
profits = c(100,200,300)
data1 = data.frame(companies,profits)

CP <- ggplot(data1, aes(x = data1$companies,y = data1$profits,fill =data1$companies )) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + 
    scale_x_discrete(name = "Companies",labels = 1:length(data1$companies))
```

Currently I have [image]

Comment: Why not just `ggplot(data1, aes(x = companies, y = profits, fill = companies)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')` and get rid of the legend all together?

Comment: I hava 50 companies and their names does not fit to x axes. So I need to add nums to x axes and show in legend, which bar correspond to company's profit

Comment: @5th, Great.But how to remove rectangles and colours from legend and plot?

Comment: I am not sure that I totally understand what you want. Do you want to remove the legend but keep the text description (i.e. 1. Company) as the reference for x-axis?

Comment: Adding `+ theme(legend.position = 'none')` to the code above will remove the legend. It is easier for a user to not read a legend unnecessarily. Others answered how to paste a number in front.

Answer (score 1):

What you might be looking for is paste:

```
newcompanies <- paste(1:50,companies,sep=".")
```

Personal (style) suggestion: 
Search how you can change the colours to one colour-range. For fifty companies this colour-range will be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `seq_along` and `paste` to make the plot you want as follow:

```
ggplot(data1, aes(x=seq_along(companies), weight=profits,
                  fill=paste(seq_along(companies), companies))) + 
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_discrete("Companies") +
  labs(x="Company Labels", y="Count")
```

[image]